# How to implement Google Directions API for unknown destination?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, direction

I'm a beginner in android studio and I'm currently create cycling apps for my final project. in these apps I need to implement Maps and Direction API. I search for tutorials, but they all set the destination. and in my apps the destination is unknown.

it's possible if I display the current location (automatic) and draw a line in Maps while the user is riding, please give a tutorial too? And it's possible if I use a Free API Key for this project?

thank you ...

Comment: What do you mean by destination is unknown? Does user need to set it?

Comment: Please check the [doc] (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start)

Comment: user doesn't set the destination, depend on where he is going.
so, the apps will track user from where he's starting to wherever he goes.
sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, This direction API is not free.
2nd you need to provide start and endpoint for direction API routes.
You can use the current location as your start point and if you have no destination then where do you want to draw a line? Means from your current location to where?

or If you want to draw a tracking line from your starting position to your current position then you don't need Direction API, you just need Live location tracking and can draw Polylines on your map using current location. Following is the code for your help.

To get this library into our app, we need to add the following to our build.gradle file.

```
implement 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.20'
```

// Initialize Geo Context First

```
private GeoApiContext getGeoContext() {
    GeoApiContext geoApiContext = new GeoApiContext();
    return geoApiContext.setQueryRateLimit(3)
            .setApiKey(getString(R.string.directionsApiKey))
            .setConnectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setReadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setWriteTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

// This code will fetch the result from Google direction api from origin to destination

```
    DateTime now = new DateTime();
    DirectionsResult result = DirectionsApi.newRequest(getGeoContext()).mode(TravelMode.DRIVING).origin(origin)
.destination(destination)
.departureTime(now).await();
```

// You can use this method to add marker on the map

```
private void addMarkersToMap(DirectionsResult results, GoogleMap mMap) {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(results.routes[0].legs[0].startLocation.lat, results.routes[0].legs[0].startLocation.lng)).title(results.routes[0].legs[0].startAddress));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(results.routes[0].legs[0].endLocation.lat, results.routes[0].legs[0].endLocation.lng)).title(results.routes[0].legs[0].startAddress).snippet(getEndLocationTitle(results)));
}
```

// Use this method to draw polyline/routes on your map

```
private void addPolyline(DirectionsResult results, GoogleMap mMap) {
    List<LatLng> decodedPath = PolyUtil.decode(results.routes[0].overviewPolyline.getEncodedPath());
    mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(decodedPath));
}
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, it helps a lot,
I'm too confused with my final project, because of the deadline and search with the wrong keyword.

now I know what I need is live location tracking with a polyline

Comment: hello after upgrading api level 30 polyline is not drawing in my case is there any solution? it return directionsResult as null